# Understanding how magento merges layout XML data

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, layout-update

How does Magento handle layout XML files?

For example if I have created a theme `app/design/frontend/example/theme` and copy an XML file from the `base/default/layout` directory in my theme's layout directory:

- Does it override the whole file? Meaning will I have to copy the XML file into my theme to begin overriding things, or
- Does it merge with the base/default and override only the changes I have made in my XML file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In brief, this is how Magento loads layout files:

1. When loading a theme, Magento reads the configuration of all the available modules, and checks which layout files should be loaded.
2. For each file, Magento tries to load it from your theme.
   If it exists in your theme, it loads it and goes directly to step 4.
3. If the file doesn't exist in your theme, it tries to load it from the `base/default` theme.
4. Magento parses the XML files and merges them into one.
5. Magento looks for a `local.xml` file in your theme, and appends whatever is there, to the previously merged layout handles.

So, unless absolutely required,

- Use the `local.xml` for changing the layout of a theme, instead of copy/pasting the xml files from base to your theme.
- Create your own layout files for your own custom modules.

> **Tip**
>   It - almost - doesn't matter if a layout handle exists in `foo.xml` or `bar.xml`.
>   I've seen implementation where people copy/paste `catalog.xml` to their own theme, because they think that's the only place where they can edit "catalog-related" handles.
>   The difference you would notice between adding a handle in `foo.xml` instead of `bar.xml`, is that a block would be appended in a different order, depending on which layout file was first loaded.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought. Also, for example all of the core XML layouts are defined within their modules - i.e. `Mage_Catalog` defines `catalog.xml` which obviously does it's own layout stuff.  I also understand how `local.xml` works - just i've been working on a site that's hacked to f**k and from what you've said, it sounds like my theme entirely overrides the `base/default/layout` files except what's inside of `local.xml` and any extensions XML which should really be extended (using: `<depends/>`) if they need to be customised.

Comment: Good answer, but don't forget that you have the option to add a theme.xml file in Magento >=1.9 to change the fallback mechanism